# How to append Text in JTextPane?

Tags: jtextpane

How to append Text in JTextPane like JTextArea?
like

```
JTextPane pText1 = new JTextPane();
pText1.append( txt1.getText + "\n" );
pText1.append( txt2.getText + "\n" );
pText1.append( txt3.getText + "\n" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, `JTextPane` works with `Document` model such as`StyledDocument` to manage text data. Because `JTextPane` differs from `JTextArea` in the sense that, we use `JTextPane` for styling text. However, if you need to append-string feature for your own requirement, you can easily build your won `appendString` function by extending `JTextPane` to work with:

```
public void appendString(String str) throws BadLocationException
{
     StyledDocument document = (StyledDocument) jTextPane.getDocument();
     document.insertString(document.getLength(), str, null);
                                                    // ^ or your style attribute  
 }
```

The above function first ask the text pane to for the `StyledDocument` associating with it. Then it make use of [`insertString(int offset,
                String str,
                AttributeSet a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#insertString%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29) function.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see where is variable JTextPane pText1, so how could your code add string to pText1?

Comment: well replace `jTextPane` with `pText1`, i used `jTextPane` to mark an instance of `JTextPane`. So replace it with yours one if required.

Comment: this is nice, but the output won't be html-formatted anymore. Any further ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

There is no append method in JTextPane objects. Most used, similar to "append":

```
JTextPane pText1 = new JTextPane();
pText1.setText(txt1.getText + "\n");
pText1.setText(pText1.getText() + txt2.getText + "\n");
pText1.setText(pText1.getText() + txt3.getText + "\n");
```

Comment: (1-) This is not a good approach. The text is stored in a Document with a "\n" to represent a new line. When you invoke getText() on the text pane the Document is parsed and the "\n" is replaced with the newline string for your platform (which in Windows is "\r\n". Then when you use setText(), you need to recreate the text in the Document which means you now need to parse the text containing the "\r\n" and replace it with "\n". As the number of lines increases this obviously becomes more inefficient. Updating the Document directly is far more efficient.